# Javascript на срабатывает при переходе внутри сайта

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Приложение на Ruby on Rails. Javascript работает нормально при прямом заходе на страницу, но если переходить внутри приложения со страницы на страницу (например по ссылке в меню) то сама страница прорисовывается нормально, но javascript не срабатывает. В чем может быть проблема?

Скрипт (с шаблона):

```js
;(function () {
 
 'use strict';



 // iPad and iPod detection 
 var isiPad = function(){
  return (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPad") != -1);
 };

 var isiPhone = function(){
     return (
   (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1) || 
   (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPod") != -1)
     );
 };

 // Parallax
 var parallax = function() {
  $(window).stellar();
 };



 // Burger Menu
 var burgerMenu = function() {

  $('body').on('click', '.js-fh5co-nav-toggle', function(event){

   event.preventDefault();

   if ( $('#navbar').is(':visible') ) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
   } else {
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
   }

   
   
  });

 };


 var goToTop = function() {

  $('.js-gotop').on('click', function(event){
   
   event.preventDefault();

   $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('html').offset().top
   }, 500);
   
   return false;
  });
 
 };


 // Page Nav
 var clickMenu = function() {

  $('#navbar a:not([class="external"])').click(function(event){
   var section = $(this).data('nav-section'),
    navbar = $('#navbar');

    if ( $('[data-section="' + section + '"]').length ) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('[data-section="' + section + '"]').offset().top
        }, 500);
      }

      if ( navbar.is(':visible')) {
       navbar.removeClass('in');
       navbar.attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
       $('.js-fh5co-nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
      }

      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
  });


 };

 // Reflect scrolling in navigation
 var navActive = function(section) {

  var $el = $('#navbar > ul');
  $el.find('li').removeClass('active');
  $el.each(function(){
   $(this).find('a[data-nav-section="'+section+'"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
  });

 };

 var navigationSection = function() {

  var $section = $('section[data-section]');
  
  $section.waypoint(function(direction) {
     
     if (direction === 'down') {
       navActive($(this.element).data('section'));
     }
  }, {
     offset: '150px'
  });

  $section.waypoint(function(direction) {
     if (direction === 'up') {
       navActive($(this.element).data('section'));
     }
  }, {
     offset: function() { return -$(this.element).height() + 155; }
  });

 };


 


 // Window Scroll
 var windowScroll = function() {
  var lastScrollTop = 0;

  $(window).scroll(function(event){

      var header = $('#fh5co-header'),
    scrlTop = $(this).scrollTop();

   if ( scrlTop > 500 && scrlTop <= 2000 ) {
    header.addClass('navbar-fixed-top fh5co-animated slideInDown');
   } else if ( scrlTop <= 500) {
    if ( header.hasClass('navbar-fixed-top') ) {
     header.addClass('navbar-fixed-top fh5co-animated slideOutUp');
     setTimeout(function(){
      header.removeClass('navbar-fixed-top fh5co-animated slideInDown slideOutUp');
     }, 100 );
    }
   } 
   
  });
 };



 // Animations
 // Home

 var homeAnimate = function() {
  if ( $('#fh5co-home').length > 0 ) { 

   $('#fh5co-home').waypoint( function( direction ) {
          
    if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated') ) {


     setTimeout(function() {
      $('#fh5co-home .to-animate').each(function( k ) {
       var el = $(this);
       
       setTimeout ( function () {
        el.addClass('fadeInUp animated');
       },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );
       
      });
     }, 200);

     
     $(this.element).addClass('animated');
      
    }
   } , { offset: '80%' } );

  }
 };

 var customersAnimate = function() {
  if ( $('#fh5co-customers').length > 0 ) {

   $('#fh5co-customers').waypoint( function( direction ) {

    if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated') ) {


     setTimeout(function() {
      $('#fh5co-customers .to-animate').each(function( k ) {
       var el = $(this);

       setTimeout ( function () {
        el.addClass('fadeInUp animated');
       },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );

      });
     }, 200);


     $(this.element).addClass('animated');

    }
   } , { offset: '80%' } );

  }
 };

 var introAnimate = function() {
  if ( $('#fh5co-intro').length > 0 ) { 

   $('#fh5co-intro').waypoint( function( direction ) {
          
    if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated') ) {


     setTimeout(function() {
      $('#fh5co-intro .to-animate').each(function( k ) {
       var el = $(this);
       
       setTimeout ( function () {
        el.addClass('fadeInRight animated');
       },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );
       
      });
     }, 1000);

     
     $(this.element).addClass('animated');
      
    }
   } , { offset: '80%' } );

  }
 };

 var workAnimate = function() {
  if ( $('#fh5co-work').length > 0 ) { 

   $('#fh5co-work').waypoint( function( direction ) {
          
    if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated') ) {


     setTimeout(function() {
      $('#fh5co-work .to-animate').each(function( k ) {
       var el = $(this);
       
       setTimeout ( function () {
        el.addClass('fadeInUp animated');
       },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );
       
      });
     }, 200);

     
     $(this.element).addClass('animated');
      
    }
   } , { offset: '80%' } );

  }
 };


 var testimonialAnimate = function() {
  var testimonial = $('#fh5co-testimonials');
  if ( testimonial.length > 0 ) { 

   testimonial.waypoint( function( direction ) {
          
    if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated') ) {

     var sec = testimonial.find('.to-animate').length,
      sec = parseInt((sec * 200) - 400);

     setTimeout(function() {
      testimonial.find('.to-animate').each(function( k ) {
       var el = $(this);
       
       setTimeout ( function () {
        el.addClass('fadeInUp animated');
       },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );
       
      });
     }, 200);

     setTimeout(function() {
      testimonial.find('.to-animate-2').each(function( k ) {
       var el = $(this);
       
       setTimeout ( function () {
        el.addClass('fadeInDown animated');
       },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );
       
      });
     }, sec);

     
     $(this.element).addClass('animated');
      
    }
   } , { offset: '80%' } );

  }
 };

 var servicesAnimate = function() {
  var services = $('#fh5co-services');
  if ( services.length > 0 ) { 

   services.waypoint( function( direction ) {
          
    if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated') ) {

     var sec = services.find('.to-animate').length,
      sec = parseInt((sec * 200) + 400);

     setTimeout(function() {
      services.find('.to-animate').each(function( k ) {
       var el = $(this);
       
       setTimeout ( function () {
        el.addClass('fadeInUp animated');
       },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );
       
      });
     }, 200);

     setTimeout(function() {
      services.find('.to-animate-2').each(function( k ) {
       var el = $(this);
       
       setTimeout ( function () {
        el.addClass('bounceIn animated');
       },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );
       
      });
     }, sec);


     
     $(this.element).addClass('animated');
      
    }
   } , { offset: '80%' } );

  }
 };

 var aboutAnimate = function() {
  var about = $('#fh5co-about');
  if ( about.length > 0 ) { 

   about.waypoint( function( direction ) {
          
    if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated') ) {


     setTimeout(function() {
      about.find('.to-animate').each(function( k ) {
       var el = $(this);
       
       setTimeout ( function () {
        el.addClass('fadeInUp animated');
       },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );
       
      });
     }, 200);

     

     $(this.element).addClass('animated');
      
    }
   } , { offset: '80%' } );

  }
 };

 var countersAnimate = function() {
  var counters = $('#fh5co-counters');
  if ( counters.length > 0 ) { 

   counters.waypoint( function( direction ) {
          
    if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated') ) {

     var sec = counters.find('.to-animate').length,
      sec = parseInt((sec * 200) + 400);

     setTimeout(function() {
      counters.find('.to-animate').each(function( k ) {
       var el = $(this);
       
       setTimeout ( function () {
        el.addClass('fadeInUp animated');
       },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );
       
      });
     }, 200);

     setTimeout(function() {
      counters.find('.js-counter').countTo({
        formatter: function (value, options) {
            return value.toFixed(options.decimals);
         },
      });
     }, 400);

     setTimeout(function() {
      counters.find('.to-animate-2').each(function( k ) {
       var el = $(this);
       
       setTimeout ( function () {
        el.addClass('bounceIn animated');
       },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );
       
      });
     }, sec);

     

     

     $(this.element).addClass('animated');
      
    }
   } , { offset: '80%' } );

  }
 };


 var contactAnimate = function() {
  var contact = $('#fh5co-contact');
  if ( contact.length > 0 ) { 

   contact.waypoint( function( direction ) {
          
    if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated') ) {

     setTimeout(function() {
      contact.find('.to-animate').each(function( k ) {
       var el = $(this);
       
       setTimeout ( function () {
        el.addClass('fadeInUp animated');
       },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );
       
      });
     }, 200);

     $(this.element).addClass('animated');
      
    }
   } , { offset: '80%' } );

  }
 };


 
 


 
 

 // Document on load.
 $(function(){

  parallax();

  burgerMenu();

  clickMenu();

  windowScroll();

  navigationSection();

  goToTop();


  // Animations
  homeAnimate();
  customersAnimate();
  introAnimate();
  workAnimate();
  testimonialAnimate();
  servicesAnimate();
  aboutAnimate();
  countersAnimate();
  contactAnimate();
  

 });


}());
```

Подключен при помощи javascript_include_tag

Comment: В Turbolinks, скорее всего.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В проекте Rails 5 по-умолчанию включен гем `turbolinks`. Подробно о нем можно прочесть в [официальном репозитории](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/).

> Обычно переходы по ссылкам приводят к полной перезагрузке страницы в браузере. Мы видим белый экран, на котором постепенно прогружается новая страница. Гем `turbolinks` меняет этот процесс - он получает новую страницу AJAX-ово, через js, и, получив ее, заменяет на текущей странице содержимое `<body>`. И у вас как у пользователя возникает ощущение мгновенного перехода к другой странице, будто вы сидите в веб-приложении на Angular/Ember/React (SPA).

И из-за такого поведения у вас могут не срабатывать скрипты. Раньше каждый переход приводил к полной загрузке новой страницы, со всеми скриптами, и их выполнением. Теперь, с `turbolinks`, скрипты и стили (и все содержимое `<head>`) загружается лишь один раз - при первом открытии сайта. И выполняются скрипты такого вида..

```
;(function () {
  ...
}());
```

..только один этот раз.

Но `turbolinks` решает эту проблему. При переходе к страницам, этот гем генерирует js-события, к которым можно привязать запуск скриптов. Например, так:

```
$(document).bind('turbolinks:load', function() {
  ...
});
```

Просто оберните ваши скрипты в такую конструкцию, и они станут выполняться каждый раз, когда будет загружена новая страница - через `turbolinks` или нет.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде сработало. Теперь 2/3 случаев открывает страницы нормально и 1/3 начинает показывать js, а затем содержимое страницы пропадает, но тут скорее косяк в самом js.